# Whats the difference between ASCII code and binary in representation

Tags: binary, ascii

Say 5 as a value.
In ASCII code its 00110101 and in binary it is 00000101.
How can we explain this in a right way.

As i know the binary is equivalent to the equation 2^2 + 2^0 = 5.
How should i explain the ASCII part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`5` is a value, but this `5` you are asking about is not a value in the ASCII table but a character or in other words an entity, so it is not 5, but "5". And it just happens that "5" is at the position 53.

You are mixing up a value itself and its index's value, but you are able to do it because we (humans) understand "5" as a number and know that it is a measure of quantity. If you run this logic on "A" it will fail, as "A" is not a number and you won't be able to represent it as sum of the power of 2s.

But in the ASCII table there is "A", it has an index and that index has a value, but they are not related at all.

Comment: This gets to the confusion we often see with fonts - it may be difficult to tell an "l" (lower-case letter L) from a 1 or a "1". Ditto O and 0

Comment: Hello thanks for your response. But im not quite sure if thats how we explain the difference between 5 as represented in ASCII code (i.e.,00110101) and 5 as represented in binary (i.e., 00000101).

Comment: That is why Microsoft doesn't allow certain characters in their 25 letter product keys.(`015AEILNOSUZ`), so the reduced set would be unambiguous.

Comment: @Han Because there are none. 5 and its position in the ASCII has nothing to do with each other. And no, 5 is NOT represented in ASCII code, you are again mixing the `value` and its `index`. `00110101` is not 5, it is its position in the ASCII table.
But again, try this logic with "A" or anything else that is not representable in binary.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, we have two things. 
1. Value(integer)
2. Character

Now, if you say '5', it is a character. and 5 is the integral value.

The characters are always stored in the form of ASCII/UNICODE or something like that.

Now, '5' has the ASCII 53 which in BINARY makes 00110101

And 5 as the number makes 00000101.

Comment: What is this `integral value`? What is the `integral value` of "Z"?

Comment: @karatedog

I think you have mistaken my point. Let me try to make it more clear.